# Why is the ListView empty?

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-listview

I am trying to make a **listView** that contains **only images without texts** but it gives a white screen and I am not getting any error or anything.

**Here is my codes:**

xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="3">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2">

    <ListView 
       android:id="@+id/setOneListView"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>

   .........

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity:**

```
public class Set1_Activity extends Activity {

ListView list;
int[] images = {
        R.drawable.iv1, R.drawable.iv2, R.drawable.iv3, R.drawable.iv4,
        R.drawable.iv5, R.drawable.iv6, R.drawable.iv11, R.drawable.iv12,
        R.drawable.iv13, R.drawable.iv14, R.drawable.iv15, R.drawable.iv16,
        R.drawable.iv111, R.drawable.iv112, R.drawable.iv113, R.drawable.iv114,
        R.drawable.iv115, R.drawable.iv116, R.drawable.iv7, R.drawable.iv8, 
        R.drawable.iv9, R.drawable.iv19, R.drawable.iv49, R.drawable.iv50,
        R.drawable.iv52, R.drawable.iv54
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.setOneListView);
    HeartlessAdapter adapter = new HeartlessAdapter(this, images);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            switch(position){
               case 0:
                   display.setImageResource(R.drawable.iv1);
                tophone = R.drawable.iv1;
                break;
           .........

class HeartlessAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
Context context;
int[] images;

HeartlessAdapter(Context c, int imgs[])
{
    super(c, R.layout.imageview);
    this.context=c;
    this.images=imgs;
}

class MyViewHolder
{
    ImageView myImage;

    MyViewHolder(View v)
    {
        myImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View row = convertView; 
    MyViewHolder holder = null;
    if(row==null)
    {
       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imageview, parent, false);
       holder = new MyViewHolder(row);
       row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (MyViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    holder.myImage.setImageResource(images[position]);


    return row;
}
}
```

All works fine, no error and the emulator just show empty white screen nothing inside. What could be missing?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems it's because of the `android:layout_weight` of the Relative layout which is wrapping the `ListView`.

Comment: @YeLinAung I removed it and made the relative layout to fill_parrent and nothing changed still a white blank screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Let `HeartlessAdapter` extend `ArrayAdapter<Integer>` instead of `ArrayAdapter<String>`.

2) on your constructor, call `super(c, R.layout.imageview, imgs);` It should work like that.

3) If you wanna optimize it a lot, remove the references to Context and the array of images from the adapter. You can get any item you need calling `getItem(position)` and the Context by calling `getContext()`.

EDIT:

In order for it to work, call this:

```
super(c, R.layout.imageview, HeartlessAdapter.toIntegerArray(imgs));
```

and add this method to `HeartlessAdapter`:

```
private static Integer[] toIntegerArray(int[] array){
    Integer[] finalArray = new Integer[array.length];
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        finalArray[i] = array[i];
    }
    return finalArray;
}
```

Comment: The actual reason why it doesn't work is you're not actually adding the items to the adapter, btw. The items are added in the super call or by calling the `add` or `addAll` methods, then calling `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Comment: when I enter "imgs" in my constructor it tells me "The constructor ArrayAdapter<Integer>(Context, int, int[]) is undefined"

Comment: I edited my answer. You just need to convert the `int` array to an `Integer` array.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the `android:layout_weight="2"` up a level to the horizontal LinearLayout.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be the problem :/

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            });
```

Comment: This answer could use more detail.

Comment: you can add more details :D